# orthogonal base in inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to solve this problem:

Let $V$ be an inner product space over a field $F$. And let $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ be linearly independent vectors such that:

$\forall \space v\in V: \left\|v\right\|^2=\left|\langle v,u_1\rangle\right|^2+\ldots + \left|\langle v,u_k\rangle\right|^2$.

I need to prove:

1. $V=\operatorname{span}\{u_1,...,u_k\}$
2. $u_1,\ldots,u_k $ are orthogonal base of $V$.

I succeeded in solving the first part, but not the second. Any suggestions? thanks for helpers!

Comment: Just put $v = u_1, u_2,..., u_n$ in the given equation

Comment: no. in the left side you have $\|u_i\|^2$ and in the right $\|u_i\|^4$

Comment: Are you sure that your question is correct? If we think that this base is orthogonal then for $u_i$ we have $\Vert u_i\Vert^2=\Vert u_i\Vert^4$ so since $u_i$ can not be zero we have $\Vert u_i\Vert=1$. In my opinion we should either assume that $\Vert u_i\Vert=1$ or derive it from your assumptions.

Comment: I thought about it too. maybe we need to show first that $\|u_i\|=1$. I showed that $\|u_i\|<=1$

Answer (score 2):

This is harder than I thought, which makes it an interesting exercise.

I'm assuming that $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $F = \mathbb{C}$, otherwise I don't know what an inner product space is. Note that *a priori* $V$ could be an infinite dimensional vector space, although it turns out $\dim V = k$.

1. Let $W = \operatorname{span}(u_1, \dots, u_k)$. For $w \in W^\perp$, choosing $v = w$ in your equation shows that $w = 0$. So we just showed that $W^\perp = \{0\}$, which is the same as saying that $W$ is dense in $V$: $\overline{W} = V$. But since $W$ is finite dimensional, it is closed: $\overline{W} = W$, so we indeed have $W = \overline{W} = V$.
2. First note that choosing $v = u_i$ yields $\Vert u_i \Vert ^2 \geqslant \Vert u_i \Vert ^4$, so that we must have $\Vert u_i \Vert^2 \leqslant 1$ for all $i\in \{1, \dots, k\}$. Now, fix $i_0 \in \{1, \dots, k\}$ and let $v \in \operatorname{span}\{u_i, i \neq i_0\}^\perp$. For this $v$, your equation says $\Vert v \Vert ^2 = \left|\langle v, u_{i_0} \rangle\right|^2$. If we consider the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\left|\langle v, u_{i_0} \rangle\right|^2 \leqslant \Vert v \Vert ^2 \, \Vert u_{i_0} \Vert ^2 $, we must conclude that $\Vert u_{i_0} \Vert = 1$ and that equality holds in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which implies that $v$ and $ u_{i_0}$ are linearly dependent. So, we have shown that $\operatorname{span}\{u_i, i \neq i_0\}^\perp \subset \operatorname{span}\{u_{i_0}\}$, in fact they must be equal because they have same dimension 1. Now we're done: it follows that $\langle u_{i_0}, u_i\rangle = 0$ for all $i \neq i_0$, and this works for any $i_0$.

Note that $(u_1, \dots, u_k)$ must be actually an orthonormal basis.

Comment: By the way, where did I use the fact that $u_1, \dots, u_k$ are linearly independent? :)

Comment: to be honest, it was not given in the source, I thought it has to be, because if not, they aare not orthogonal. but if you can prove that they are linearly independent I will be grateful. and thanks a lot!

Comment: You are (as you say in a comment, although you then seem to dismiss it) using linear independence when you pick a $v\ne0$. If $u_i$ is in the span of the others, then this step fails. And linear independence is needed. In short, because e.g. $\lvert x\rvert^2=\lvert x\cdot(1/\sqrt2)\rvert^2+\lvert x\cdot(1/\sqrt2)\rvert^2$.

Comment: You're right, I use it because I need $\dim \operatorname{span}\{u_i, i \neq i_0\}^\perp \geqslant 1$ (to conclude that $\operatorname{span}\{u_i, i \neq i_0\}^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{u_{i_0}\}$). I'll delete my previous comments.